# Jeep wont start after thunder storm

Tags: battery-drain

Vehicle was running fine same day prior to storm and never had any indication of battery or power issues. Then we had a thunder storm and there was a significant strike close by over head with no actual ground contact and when I went out after the storm my jeep wouldn't start. There was enough power for radio and dash lights but it wouldn't turn over. It would take a boost though, but not keep the charge. 
Can an overhead lightning burst cause damage to a car battery? I was thinking it was some kind of fluke EMP burst.

Comment: Welcome to the site @George, what makes you sure there was no ground contact?

Comment: Might want to check the alternator.  Could be the alternator died.  Had enough power to get there, but not enough to restart.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries die eventually, often when you least expect them to die. Might be completely casual and unrelated. Try a new battery.

Comment: +1 While electrical damage from lightning strikes is a possibility a battery ought to be the least affected one. As long as radio and dash lights won't indicate an error I would exclude lightning strikes/EMP like stuff..

Comment: Yeah, EMP is Death for solid state electronics, and car batteries surely don't contain solid state electronics.